# DBus Finch/Pidgin without X11

Tags: python, x11, dbus, finch, pidgin

I want to do some Python scripting on my server where I can communicate with `finch` (A console interface of `pidgin`, with the interface looking like `links2`) through the DBus Python library to send messages or check for buddy online status.

This **works** if you do it in X. Run `finch` in an X terminal and run the Python script in another terminal with no errors/exceptions.

But if you do it **without X**, you have to run `finch` in TTY1 (ctrl+alt+f1) and the python script in TTY2 (ctrl+alt+f2) but the python script will **fail**.

The following is the first few lines of the script:

```
import dbus
bus = dbus.SessionBus() # gives EXCEPTION error
obj = bus.get_object("im.pidgin.purple.PurpleService", "/im/pidgin/purple/PurpleObject")
...
```

The EXCEPTION error is:

```
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed: dbus-launch failed to autolaunch D-Bus session: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.`
```

I read somewhere that maybe you need to run `finch` and the script both in the same TTY. However I am unable to test that properly because it is not like running `cd` on one line and `ls` on the next line. You type `finch` , it runs, and you can't type any other commands anymore, like `links2`. I tried running `finch &` instead but that seems to pause `finch`, and running the script also gives the same error.

Solution? Thanks.

Comment: I basically want to run a script which messages someone or check someone's status without requiring X. Just something I can ssh into and run the script. Maybe you can give me an alternative solution which doesn't necessarily have to involve finch or dbus.

Comment: Thanks for asking the question and answering it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install `screen`

1. `dbus-launch screen`
2. `finch`
3. ctrl+a c
4. `python myscript`

Comment: So that's the solution, can't mark it as my answer at the moment, gotta do it tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you! I have been searching for days regarding why I can't use gvfs on a headless system. Launching dbus this way did the trick!

Comment: Thanks for this -- your pointing me to dbus-launch led me to notice that subsequent unrelated terminals can connect to dbus by setting the DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS environment variable, which presumably does the job when $DISPLAY is unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

I think finch needs some display. To launch it on the server try to use **xvfb-run**: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb

Comment: No, finch itself runs fine without X.

Comment: Are you sure that dbus-daemon is running? (normally x11 starts it)

Comment: X11 does not start dbus-daemon, dbus-daemon is usually started by the desktop environment.

Comment: It's running but maybe there is a 'disconnect' between dbus and finch. Just guessing.